# Using JQuery methods to find the class. Using a JavaScript file in a rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, local-storage

The texts 'pearl' and 'diamond' are elements in an array stored in localStorage. I couldn't find any good resources to help me pull the data from localStorage so I can display and manipulate the data in rails. Thus, I wrote a function in my application.js file to help me find the texts and the surrounding classes.

Here's the info in html.

```
<div class="ruby-gem">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/pearl">pearl</a>
  <img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png" alt="star pic">
</div>
<div class="ruby-gem">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/diamond">diamond</a>
  <img class="star-pic" src="/assets/star-gray.png" alt="star pic">
</div>
```

Here's my function in the application.js file. Right now the variable findSrc is undefined.

```
function checkStorage(){
  var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rubygems"))
  var gems = $(".ruby-gem a").map(function(){
    return $(this).text()
  }).get()
  for (var i = 0; i < gems.length; i++){
    if(storage.includes(gems[i])){
      var gemFavorite = gems[i]
      var findDiv = $("a:contains(gemFavorite)")
      var findImgClass = findDiv.next()
      var findSrc = $(findImgClass).find("img").attr("src")
      if(findSrc == "/assets/star-gray.png"){
        $(findImgClass).attr("src", "/assets/star-blue.png")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to change the image from a gray star to a blue star if the item(s) are located in localStorage. This is probably not the best way to do it but I couldn't figure out a nicer solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$("a:contains(gemFavorite)")`, doesn't automatically switch the contents of the variable gemFavorite into that spot, you need to do actual string concatenation or use template literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have neglected to insert the **gemFavorite** variable into the selector string correctly.

```js
var findDiv = $("a:contains(" + gemFavorite + ")")
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store them in localStorage? Where do 'pearl' and 'diamond' come from?

I could imagine something like they're data from the previous page?

If i were you i would store the array in the params, when it's only two we are talking about.

For example

*I'm only guessing*

Previous page:

```
<a href="link_to_the_page_your_showing?#{{p: "pearl", d:"diamond"}.to_query}">
Go blue star!</a>
<!-- output in the url on next page: "d=diamond&p=pearl" -->
<a href="link_to_the_page_your_showing">Go boring gray star!</a>
```

Your page:

```
<!-- Using erb to manipulate the src in img -->
<div class="ruby-gem">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/pearl">pearl</a>
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/<%= params[:p] == "pearl" ? "star-
blue" : "star-gray" %>.png" alt="star pic">
</div>
<div class="ruby-gem">
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.com/diamond">diamond</a>
<img class="star-pic" src="/assets/<%= params[:d] == "diamond" ? "star-
blue" : "star-gray" %>.png" alt="star pic">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes, 'pearl' and 'diamond' come from a previous page. The assignment is to store the items in localStorage. They want the data stored on the client side not on the server side.  The line of code from the previous answer works but still having a difficult time changing the "src". If there's a better way to pull the information from localStorage so I can manipulate it in erb that would be better.

Comment: Are they okay with cookies?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Which is why it's making head spin. :)

Comment: Tricky, but i have an idea! :)

Comment: LOL. Thanks for your help!